# How to draw a CImage on Picture Control? MFC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, computer-vision, mfc

I'm building a histogram tool, that shall display the histogram of a live camera input.
The framerate is really slow with only 4fps.
I'm new to MFC, but got an example from the camera manufacturer that uses MFC to display the camera output on a picture control. At them moment I'm stuck trying to simply display a CImage on a picture control.

I'm getting a completely black output.
What am I doing wrong?

```
void Capp3Dlg::OnBnClickedbtncalc()
{
int histoWidth = 255;
int histoHeight = 100;
CImage histo;
histo.Create(histoWidth, histoHeight, 8, NULL);

CRect rect; // define a rectangular class
CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_Histo); //Get the handle of the control
pWnd->GetClientRect(&rect); //Get the handle to the size of the control area
CDC* pDc = pWnd->GetDC(); //Get the DC of the picture

//const int pixSum = histoWidth * histoHeight;
BYTE rValues[25500];
BYTE gValues[25500];
BYTE bValues[25500];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(rValues); i++) {
    rValues[i] = 255;
    gValues[i] = 0;
    bValues[i] = 0;
}

for (int h = 0;h < histoHeight;h++)
{
    for (int w = 0;w < histoWidth;w++)
    {
        int index = h * histoWidth + w;
        unsigned char* pucColor = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*> (histo.GetPixelAddress(w, h));
        pucColor[0] = bValues[index];
        pucColor[1] = gValues[index];
        pucColor[2] = rValues[index];
    }
}

int nWindowW = rect.Width(); 
int nWindowH = rect.Height();   
int nImageW = histo.GetWidth();   
int nImageH = histo.GetHeight(); 
float ratioW = (float)nWindowW / nImageW;
float ratioH = (float)nWindowH / nImageH;
if (ratioW < ratioH)
    histo.Draw(pDc->m_hDC, 0, (int)(nWindowH - nImageH * ratioW) / 2, nWindowW, (int)(nImageH * ratioW), 0, 0, nImageW, nImageH);
else
    histo.Draw(pDc->m_hDC, (int)(nWindowW - nImageW * ratioH) / 2, 0, (int)(nImageW * ratioH), nWindowH, 0, 0, nImageW, nImageH);

ReleaseDC(pDc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake.

The `nBpp` on the `CImage.Create` has to be `3*8` to work properly.